# Why are there so many variants of an Op Amp? Which one to chose?

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, texas-instruments

I am directed in a [user manual](https://components.omron.com/us-en/ds_related_pdf/A282-E1.pdf) (Page 10) to use the LMV324 Amplifier. But when I search on the [net](https://www.google.com/search?q=lmv324&sxsrf=APq-WBsQRQijxHEp4wmabLxNHyeP84w0Dw:1650887420990&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP6qrykq_3AhU37nMBHZl9BGoQ_AUoBHoECAEQHQ&biw=1536&bih=760&dpr=1.25) there are just too many types of this amplifier with a lot of different types of suffixes. I need to know which one to use and if this amplifier is available in THT type to anyone's knowledge.

Comment: Pick one (probably the cheapest). Look at it. Does it have the features you want? If yes, then order one. If no, pick another one and repeat. If you fail several times then maybe try to find out what the extra letters mean so you can search.

Comment: Datasheets should help figure out the suffixes. Look for suffix "P" as it is often used for the plastic DIP package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many factors involved in selecting any electronic component, such as the operating temperature range, required accuracy and stability, power consumption, etc.  Please update your question with more information about the application.

Because the document recommends a low voltage/low power device, I assume it is addressing a battery-powered application.  The part that is recommended will work, but newer devices using a different technology (CMOS opamps) probably will work just as well with even lower power consumption.  Is the power level important?

Another area is accuracy.  The basis for the recommended part is the LM324 quad bipolar opamp.  This is a very well known part, readily available and cheap, but not the most accurate part out there.  Figure 8 shows an input voltage range of -10 mV to +40 mV, but the LMV324 input offset voltage error can be as high as +/-7 mV.  This can be adjusted out by tweaking the circuit offset (R1/R2 or the external reference voltage at R10), but the error wanders around with changes in temperature.  The 324 probably is ok for prototyping, but I would consider changing to a more accurate part for a production unit.  The datasheet recommends the "A" version of the same part, which reduces the offset voltage error to +/-5 mV.  Other, more expensive parts are much more accurate.

According to the Texas Instruments datasheet, the LMV324 is not available in a through-hole package.  Both manufacturer's and distributor's websites have parametric search functions.  The basic requirements (operating voltage range, Input common mode voltage range, maximum input offset voltage, temperature range, and package) will reduce greatly the number of possible candidate parts.  Texas Instruments site includes National Semiconductor, and analog Devices site includes Linear Technology, all excellent analog component sources.

The recommended circuit used three separate opamps to construct what is known as an instrumentation amplifier (IA).  A common problem is that for best performance, the associated resistors must be very accurate and stable.  Another option worth considering is buying an integrated IA, a single chip with the laser-trimmed resistors built-in.  All of the other parameters (input and output voltage ranges, operating voltages, etc.) still apply in selecting one, but the difference in performance is significant.

Comment: Thanks. Can you recommend a more accurate part as you believe LMV324 is not as accurate?

Comment: I have been trying to understand your answer, and from a layman's perspective I think there is a lot I have understood but still a lot that needs to be understood. I need your help pin pointing the right part. I have LMV324IDR most conveniently available (I mean it can be easily imported into my country in my local currency payment). Its output channel current is 40mA. The other (LMV324M/NOPB) which is available on digi key is five times the price and its output channel current is 160mA. Other than the output channel current I cannot find a second difference in them. Can you guide which one?

Comment: You are right that the LMV324 data sheet recommends A version of same part, but the A part ( https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/LMV324AQDRQ1?qs=yqaQSyyJnNi2KHoxYvQKOA%3D%3D ) has an operating current of only 80uA while the sensor is working on 100uA. Are these compatible?  https://www.mouser.in/c/semiconductors/amplifier-ics/operational-amplifiers-op-amps/?m=Texas%20Instruments&series=LMV324A-Q1

Answer (score 1):

Look for the datasheet. "LM" prefix means it originated with National Semiconductor which is now owned by Texas Instruments.

[Here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv324.pdf) it is.

Everything you need is explained there. The most "hobbyist friendly" package is probably the SOIC. There are no THT packages, this being a relatively (~20 years old) modern part.

Comment: Thanks...........

Comment: Hi @Spehro, the data sheet doesn't go into details of all the variants, and there are just so many SOIC type out there. The sensor is supposed to be supplied 100uA. One variant of the amplifier works at 40uA operational supply current https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/595-LMV324Q3MAX-NOPB, one works at 80uA https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/LMV324AQDRQ1?qs=yqaQSyyJnNi2KHoxYvQKOA%3D%3D, one at 160uA https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/595-LMV324IDRE4. I just don't know which to go for. Can you help?